# ERROR EN PHYTON: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 6 7 6 5'

Tags: python

¡Hola! soy nueva en este mundo de la programación, estoy intentando hacer un código básico en phyton, pero no entiendo como solucionar el error que me presenta:

> ERROR EN PHYTON: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 6 7 6 5'

Agradezco mucho su colaboración, el error está en la siguiente línea:

```
lineas =  int(input()).split()
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
N = int(input()) #CANTIDAD DE LÍNEAS
    cumplen = []
    disponible = False

for i in range(N):
    lineas =  int(input()).split() # <-------- Aquí me marca el error
    for i in range(len(lineas[0])):  #VALORES POR LÍNEA
        if (lineas[i][0] >= 3) and (lineas[i][1] < 68) and (lineas[i][2] > 4) and (lineas[i][3] == 0) and (lineas[i][4] > 100):
          cumplen.append(lineas[i][-1])
          disponible = True

    if disponible:
        for i in cumplen:
          print(i)
    else:
      print("NO DISPONIBLE")
```

Tengo una condición. El enunciado dice lo siguiente:
"El programa imprimirá el precio de cada una de las cuentas de los usuarios morosos de la base de datos que cumplen con los criterios de Suspensión (los criterios son la linea de if).
Si no existe ningún registro en la base de datos que cumpla los criterios de Catalina, el programa imprimirá 'NO DISPONIBLE'"

Esto quiere decir el programa se verá algo así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al hacer `int(input()).split()` primero conviertes a entero una cadena con espacios lo que provoca el error, deberia ser `int(input().split())` pero también dará error, ahora elaboro una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes. al hacer `int(input()).split()` estas haciendo el `split` en un entero, lo cual no es correcto, y el error que te sale, es por que tratas de convertir una cadena con espacios `3 6 7 6 5` a entero y esto no es posible, pues solo se puede convertir *números* (en formato texto), que están en base `10`(decimal), la forma correcta de hacerlo es hacer un `split()` en el `input()`, lo cual devuelve una lista e ir iterando y convirtiendo cada elemento de la lista en entero, así:

```py
...
for i in range(N):
    lineas =  input().split() 
    numbers = []
    for num in lineas:
        lineas_sep.append(int(num))
    ...
```

Para mi esto es muy largo, por lo que se puede optar por una compresión de lista.

```py
...
for i in range(N):
    lineas =  input().split() 
    lineas = [int(num) for num in lineas]
    ...
```

Por otra parte no se por que luego haces `range(len(lineas[0]))`, esto dará error por que no puedes medir la longitud de un entero y también haces `lineas[i][0]`, pues la variable `lineas` no es una matriz, es solo una lista con `n` elementos.
Tu código debería quedar así:

```py
N = int(input()) #CANTIDAD DE LÍNEAS
cumplen = []
disponible = False

for i in range(N):
    lineas =  input().split() 
    lineas = [int(num) for num in lineas]
    for i in range(lineas[0]):  #es recomendado omitir el for
        if (lineas[0] >= 3) and (lineas[1] < 68) and (lineas[2] > 4) and (lineas[3] == 0) and (lineas[4] > 100):
          cumplen.append(lineas[i][-1])
          disponible = True

    if disponible:
        for i in cumplen:
          print(i)
    else:
      print("NO DISPONIBLE")
```

Answer (score 0):

parece que estás intentando crear una lista con valores que sean correctos en una línea.

```
N = int(input("Cantidad de líneas: ")) #CANTIDAD DE LÍNEAS
cumplen = []
disponible = False
```

el primer error en lo que pusiste es el indentado, supongo que es un error al copiar

```
for i in range(N):
lineas =  int(input()).split() # <-------- Aquí me marca el error
```

split() convierte una cadena en lista e int() una cadena en entero, no una lista completa

con comprension de listas sería:

```
for i in range(N):
    lineas =  [int(x) for x in input("Linea: ").split()]
```

donde lineas sería una lista de enteros

```
for i in range(len(lineas[0])):  #VALORES POR LÍNEA
        if (lineas[i][0] >= 3) and (lineas[i][1] < 68) and (lineas[i][2] > 4) and (lineas[i][3] == 0) and (lineas[i][4] > 100):
```

no es necesario recorrer la lista si usas sus índices, pero es solo un valor de índice:

```
if lineas[0]>= 3 and lineas[1] < 68 and lineas[2] > 4 and lineas[3] == 0 and lineas[4] > 100:
```

Donde ya especificas cual índice querés comparar.

todo completo:

```
N = int(input("Cantidad de líneas: ")) #CANTIDAD DE LÍNEAS
cumplen = []
disponible = False

for i in range(N):
    lineas =  [int(x) for x in input("Linea: ").split()]
    if lineas[0]>= 3 and lineas[1] < 68 and lineas[2] > 4 and lineas[3] == 0 and lineas[4] > 100:
        cumplen.append(lineas)
        disponible = True

    if disponible:
        for i in cumplen:
            print(i)
    else:
        print("NO DISPONIBLE")
```

en donde si ingreso los valores de tu ejemplo más una correcta da como resultado:

```
Cantidad de líneas: 2
Linea: 3 6 7 6 5
NO DISPONIBLE
Linea: 3 6 7 0 101
[3, 6, 7, 0, 101]
```

Igual guarda, porque nunca indicas la cantidad de elementos de las lineas ni que deben ser separadas por espacio, lo cual puede generar errores que no estás interceptando.

modificación para mostrar solo el último valor de la lista
con indentado 0:

```
if len(cumplen) != 0: 
    for i in cumplen:
        print(i[-1])
else:
    print("NO DISPONIBLE")
```

Comment: @LinaSofia ¿se supone que ingresas todos los datos en una sola cadena? y ¿el mayor que 100 será el número de cliente? ¿Si tomas los datos de una base, como los representas?

Comment: ¡Buenísimo!, ¡Muchas gracias!, pero supongo que no fui clara y tengo un problema, me gustaría que al final si se cumplen todas las condiciones imprima el último dato, pero solo de la línea que las cumplió y que no aparezca el print línea por línea, ¿me hago entender? En la pregunta adjunté ejemplos de como se vería, para que esté más claro  ¿puedes sugerirme algo para realizar esa modificación?

Comment: Esa fue la razón por la que agregué un len e intenté recorrer la lista, realmente no sabía que no funcionaba en enteros, ¡Gracias!

Comment: @LinaSofia agregué una modificación para cumplir que solo muestre el último elemento al final